# Monetizing android app in Trinidad and Tobago

Tags: android, google-play

I currently live in Trinidad and Tobago and I wrote an android app not realizing that Google does not yet support billing to this country.

A local bank called "Republic Bank" is offering an international US credit card.

This is where I found the info: http://www.republictt.com/1asp/personal.asp?f=cc_aa

Would I be able to use this to sell apps on android marketplace?

Comment: You need to ask a question :-)

Answer (score 1):

International banking solve the issue,,, you can open a bank account in one of the countries that google allow it to sell apps. and I've emailed google with this idea and this is their replay :

" If you are legally able to open a bank account in the US, then you can register for a Google Wallet merchant account"

of course US or the other 31 countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Admob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/), [Mobvista](http://dev.mobvista.com/user/showreg/?u=T0RZPQ==) and other ad network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to withdraw your funds via an international credit card. In case you want to monetize your app, try out other ad networks or platforms that allow you to withdraw money via wire transfer to any bank in your country, e.g. Clickky, and others.